# Ask to confirm when changing tabs in angular bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-bootstrap

I have tabs with forms and I want ask the user to confirm or discard their changes when changing tabs. My current code works

`<uib-tab heading="..." index="3" deselect="main.onDeselect($event)" ... >`

```
this.onDeselect = function($event) {
    if(...isDirty...) {         
        if($window.confirm("Do you want to discard?")) {
            ... discard (and go to new tab) ...
        } else {
            $event.preventDefault(); //stays on current tab
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I want to change confirm to javascript dialog and I will get result in callback.

I planed to `preventDefault()` all and then switch manually, but I cannot figure out where to get new tab id.

Any solution is appreciated. Even if it is easier in other tab implementations.

I use AngularJS v1.4.7, ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.min.js

Comment: Why do you want a manual switch? Is the current approach with only preventing the switch based on dialog response not working?

Comment: It works but all browsers allow user to get rid of the widnow confirm dialog and I have no option to change that. That's why I want to switch to MaterialDesign confirm dialog. Then in callback it's to late to call preventDefault().

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `$selectedIndex` and the `active` property for that purpose. See this [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vdr66sapqQchJ4CCttnx?p=preview)

One thing to be noted here is that when we manually change the active property, it again fires the deselect event which needed to be handled. Otherwise it seems to do what you wanted.

**Edit**

Indeed as noted in the comments, the `deselect` carries the HTML index rather than what is passed in in the tab index property. A workaround could be in this: [Another Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/RWUoq3SUk9t9Z6I4Je4x?p=preview). Here I'm pulling the actual index from the HTML index.

And a little research indicates that this issue might as well be fixed already with 3.0 bootstrap tpl [See this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6107).

Comment: Yes it works if you have index of the tab same as its position in html. I faced a problem when i hide one tab with ng-if, then it selects wrong tab. I changed it to ng-show and it seems ok now. Is there a way how to translate $selectedIndex to index stated in html?

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time with different approaches and this one is stable for some time. What I do is to prevent deselect at the beginning and set the new tab in callback if confirmed to loose changes...

```
    this.onDeselect = function($event, $selectedIndex) {
        var me = this;
        if(this.tabs.eventDirty || this.tabs.locationDirty || this.tabs.contractDirty) {

            $event.preventDefault();

            var alert = $mdDialog.confirm({
                title: 'Upozornění',
                textContent: 'Na záložce jsou neuložené změny. Přejete si tyto změny zrušit a přejít na novou záložku?',
                ok: 'Přijít o změny',
                cancel: 'Zůstat na záložce'
              });

             $mdDialog
                .show( alert )
                .then(function() {
                    $rootScope.$emit("discardChanges");
                    me.tabs.activeTab = $selectedIndex;
                })
        }
    };
```